# Gulp Sass Compiling Error

Tags: compiler-errors, sass, compilation, gulp

Here is my current directory tree:
[Directory Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLi80.png)

And here is my gulpfile.js code:

```
var gulp = require ('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    server = lr();

var jsSources = ['components/scripts/scriptOne.js',
                 'components/scripts/scriptTwo.js'
];

var sassSources = [
  'comptonents/sass/*.scss'
];

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(jsSources)
              .pipe(uglify())
              .pipe(concat ('script.js'))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src(sassSources)
    .pipe(sass({style: 'expanded', lineNumbers: true}))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
  var server = livereload();
  gulp.watch(jsSources, ['js']);
  gulp.watch(sassSources, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['js/script.js', '*.html'], function(e) {
    server.changed(e.path);
  });
});



gulp.task('default', ['sass','js', 'watch']);
```

The error that I am getting is outputting the following command whenever I try to run gulp to compile my sass.

```
       19:55:01] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/coffeescript/gulpfile.js
[19:55:01] Starting 'sass'...
[19:55:01] 'sass' errored after 21 ms
[19:55:01] TypeError: glob pattern string required
    at new Minimatch (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js:116:11)
    at setopts (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/node_modules/glob/common.js:118:20)
    at new GlobSync (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/node_modules/glob/sync.js:40:3)
    at Function.globSync [as sync] (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/node_modules/glob/sync.js:26:10)
    at /Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:68:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at gulpRubySass (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:67:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/gulpfile.js:27:11)
    at module.exports (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/Aquinas/Desktop/coffeescript/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
```

## Please help me out on figuring this out. Thank you.

Edit One: Changed the typo error in var SassSources. However , still output errors. I don't even have a log to check it. Sucks, I am sure I've enabled the log command. Anyways, if it helps here is the gulp plugins tree:

[Gulp plugins tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNpJM.png)

Edit Two: SOLVED!! I had to point the live reload number (provided from the xxx in my index.html). I had to make a few adjustments to my code, and viola! It's running like bread and butter.

Adjusted code:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen(35732);
  var server = livereload();
  gulp.watch(jsSources, ['js']);
  gulp.watch(coffeeSources, ['coffee']);
  gulp.watch(sassSources, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['js/script.js', '*.html'], function(e) {
    livereload.changed(e.path);
  });
});
```

The issue was the watch for livereload was not working because the code I was using was a little outdated.

Comment: Is that a typo : 'comptonents'? in sassSources.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for pointing that out lol! But, I've corrected it, and its still outputting the same error. I've updated the top post to show my gulp plugins tree. Thanks all!

Comment: What happens if you just put 'components/sass/*.scss' into your 'sass' task src instead of the array call to sassSources?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because **gulp.src()** expects a string and not an array as the entry file. Simply change that from array to a string and you might be good to go.

Comment: I've just noticed that Mark commented the same thing as I.